# use fakeroot/fakechroot to tar package

Tags: shell, fakeroot

There is a foo.tar.gz source it will install to /lib/modules.
But, I'm not root haven't enough permission.
I'm try to write a script to automatic build the package.

```
#!/bin/bash
tar xf foo.tar.gz
cd foo
make
fakeroot make install
```

It shows

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/lib/modules/foo.so
```

I don't want to really put in /lib, maybe I could put in $HOME/rootfs.

What is the correct method to use fakeroot?
Or, is there a simple script could let me trace how to use fakeroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about the role of `fakeroot`. It is *not* used to elevate privilges to root in order to *install* a package. It is used when a package is *created*. Since you are not creating a package, there is nothing `fakeroot` can do for you. See also this [description of fakeroot](https://web.archive.org/web/20120209044924/http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/fakeroot.htm).

To temporarily elevate privileges, you should use `sudo`.

Comment: I don't want to really install to /lib/modules.  I wish it could put on other directory.

Comment: Ah, that's easy: `make install PREFIX=/your/home/directory`, should work for "standard" packages using GNU autoconf generated makefiles and many others. If it doesn't work, you'll have to look at the makefile's `install:` target and edit it to install in your desired place.

Comment: Does that also workable on kernel source? (make modules_install)